# Using keyboard's shift + tab keys navigating through links in a list, when focus moves to a link that is out of the frame, page doesn't scroll up

Tags: html, css, list, focus, accessibility

I have a list of links:

```
<div class="cmp cmp-game-rules-list aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12">
  <div class="rules-list-wrapper">
    <h2 id="hasan">Hasan</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="">
        <a href="hasan/gholam">
          <div class="logo" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://hasan.jpg&quot;);">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <strong>gholam</strong>
            <span> Updated </span>
          </div>
          <div class="carret">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="icon icon-next">
            </svg>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="/gholi">
          <div class="logo" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://gholam.jpg&quot;);">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <strong>gholam</strong>
            <span> Updated </span>
          </div>
          <div class="carret">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="icon icon-next">
            </svg>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I tab through them down, when focus goes below the visible viewpoint, the window scrolls so I see the focused item in the viewpoint. However when I shift+tab through them up, when the focus goes above the visible viewpoint, the window doesn't scroll up until I shift+tab again. How would I fix this accessibility issue?

**Update**

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise and Firefox 72.0.2.

Comment: Can you please specify what OS and browser (including versions) that you are using? Can you please also post rendered HTML rather than Vue code? And when you say "frame", do you mean the viewport, or an actual frame? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(World_Wide_Web). Thanks!

Comment: agree with Josh, it is hard to debug your source, please provide the generated HTML. Also is the item partially in the viewport when it doesn't scroll up, as this is expected behaviour. (if you have a fixed / sticky header bear in mind that items obscured by it are still within the viewport)

Comment: I have added the additional details and added the post redndered HTML. By frames I meant viewpoint. And no the items are not partially visible, they are not visible at all. Please see the description for more info. Thanks

Comment: @GrahamRitchie please have a look at the updated description

Comment: @Josh please have a look at the updated description and my comment

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue using Firefox 72 on Windows 10. Using [SHIFT]+[TAB] seems to be correctly returning focus and scrolling out-of-viewport elements in my testing. Have you tried unloading your CSS and testing with HTML only?